# Calculus Question ( Surface area/Volume)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

An open box (I.e. no lid) had a square base of side $x$ cm and height $h$ cm. Given that the volume of box is $108$ cm$^3$.

a) Show that the surface area in cm$^2$ is given by $A = x^2 + 432/x$.

b) Use calculus to find the minimum surface area of the box, justifying your answer.

I know you would differentiate the quation to $A = 2x - 432x^{-2}$ but not sure about the next step. Would you plug in $108$ into the equation where $x$ is?

Comment: What is the equation for the volume of the box? How can you use that in conjunction with the derivative of the surface area you found to solve for x or h?

Comment: Did you mean $A' = 2x - 432x^{-2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an open box, the area consists of the bottom square plus four rectangles with sides $x$ and $h$. The area is

$$A = x^2 + 4xh.$$

Since the volume is equal to $108$ units you have

$$V = x^2 h = 108.$$

Use this relation to write the area in terms of $x$.

For question (b) differentiate, equate to zero and solve for $x$.